# System.FormatException: Wave file not valid

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, speech-recognition, formatexception

Please have a look at the following code snippet

```
using System.IO;



MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();


SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
s.setOutputToWaveStream(stream);
s.Speak("hello world");


SpeechRecognitionEngine e = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CuntureInfo("en-US");


//Set grammar code goes here

e.SetInputToWaveStream(stream);
```

when it reaches to `e.SetInputToWaveStream(stream);` it throws the error `System.FormatException: Wave file not valid`

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Need to call `stream.Position = 0` before setting it into input